# Generate all possible column vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, permutation

I am essentially trying to figure out how to generate code for basis vectors of different configurations of M objects into N different states (for example, if I had 2 snacks between 2 kids, I could have (2,0) (0,2) or (1,1), terrible example, but thats the idea)

I am struggling to figure out how to do this without going into many different loops (I want this to be automatic).  The idea would be to create a Matrix where each row is a vector of length M.  I would start with vec(1) = N then an if loop where if sum(vec) == N, Matrix(1,:)=vec;  Then I could take vec(1)=N-i and do the same.

My only issue is I do not see how to use the if and forget it so that if  I had maybe 2 objects in 5 locations, how would I do this to get (1 0 0 0 1).

I am not seeing how to do this.

Comment: So, for 5 locations and 20 objects, your vectors would include `[14 0 3 2 1]` and `[2 1 3 9 5]`?

Comment: On the exchange there is a function called `combn`.  Check to see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function:

```
function out = combos(M,N)

if N == 1
  out = M;
else
  out = [];
  for i = 0:M
    subout = combos(M-i,N-1);
    subout(:,end+1) = i;
    out = [out;subout];
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want.

The key idea is to generate not the number of elements in each group, but the *split points* between groups. This can be done via *combinations with repetition*. Matlab's `nchoosek` generates combinations without repetition, but these are easily converted into what we need.

```
M = 5; % number of objects
N = 3; % number of groups
t = nchoosek(1:M+N-1, N-1); % combinations without repetition...
t = bsxfun(@minus, t, 1:N-1); % ...convert into combinations with repetition
t = diff([zeros(size(t,1), 1) t repmat(M, size(t,1), 1) ], [], 2); % the size of each
    % group is the distance between split points
```

In this example, the result is

```
t =
     0     0     5
     0     1     4
     0     2     3
     0     3     2
     0     4     1
     0     5     0
     1     0     4
     1     1     3
     1     2     2
     1     3     1
     1     4     0
     2     0     3
     2     1     2
     2     2     1
     2     3     0
     3     0     2
     3     1     1
     3     2     0
     4     0     1
     4     1     0
     5     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar approach to Luis' without `bsxfun`. Because we don't like fun.

```
n = 5;
k = 3;

c = nchoosek(n+k-1, k-1);
result = diff([zeros(c, 1) nchoosek(1:(n+k-1), k-1) ones(c, 1)*(n+k)], [], 2) - 1;
```

This creates the partitions of the integer `n` with length `k`. Given an array of length `n + (k-1)`, we find all combinations of `(k-1)` places to place partitions between the (unary) integers. For 5 items and 3 locations, we have 7 choices of where to put the partitions:

```
[ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

If our chosen combination is `[2 4]`, we replace positions `2` and `4` with partitions to look like this:

```
[ 0 | 0 | 0 0 0 ]
```

The `O`'s give the value in unary, so this combination is `1 1 3`. To recover the values easily, we just augment the combinations with imaginary partitions at the next values to the left and right of the array (`0` and `n+k`) and take the difference and subtract `1` (because the partitions themselves don't contribute to the value):

```
diff([0 2 4 8]) - 1
ans =

   1   1   3
```

By sliding the partitions in to each possible combination of positions, we get all of the partitions of `n`.

Output:

```
result =

   0   0   5
   0   1   4
   0   2   3
   0   3   2
   0   4   1
   0   5   0
   1   0   4
   1   1   3
   1   2   2
   1   3   1
   1   4   0
   2   0   3
   2   1   2
   2   2   1
   2   3   0
   3   0   2
   3   1   1
   3   2   0
   4   0   1
   4   1   0
   5   0   0
```